# Finding the RSSI value if data is sent through XBees connecting one Raspberry Pi to another

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, xbee

I am stuck at the very basic problem of finding the RSSI value at the receiver XBee from the transmitter XBee if each the XBee is connected to a Raspberry Pi using Python. I searched the internet and found this code, but it doesn't work:

```
import zigbee, struct

rssi_raw = zigbee.ddo_get_param('[00:13:a2:00:40:0a:12:96]!', 'DB')
rssi_val = struct.unpack('=B', rssi_raw)
```

Comment: This code is not running. It produces error. It doesnot recognize   ddo_get_param.    I configured both the Xbee in AT mote. For running, may be i need to configure them in API mode. Please help.

Comment: Try this approach [Receiving data from XBee EndPoints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20109325/7414759)